# I've set a button to change the name of another button, after the change it doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I've set a button up to change the language from English to Welsh, only about 5 lines of English so just changing the text in each box manually with .setText

I also needed to change the text on the buttons, this works but once I change the language the other buttons fail to function.

The code below is what happens when the "English" button is pressed (same happens with the Welsh button is pressed..but in Welsh). Once pressed the calc, reset, calc2, and reset2 buttons stop doing the function they are set up to do...but they work before neither button is pressed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
        english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            quantity1.setText("Quantity");
            total1.setText("Minimum");

            Button calc = findViewById(R.id.buttoncalc);
            calc.setOnClickListener(this);
            calc.setText("Calculation");

            Button reset = findViewById(R.id.buttonreset);
            reset.setOnClickListener(this);
            reset.setText("Reset");

            Button calc2 = findViewById(R.id.buttoncalc2);
            calc2.setOnClickListener(this);
            calc2.setText("Calculation");

            Button reset2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonreset2);
            reset2.setOnClickListener(this);
            reset2.setText("Reset");

            multi_title.setText("Multi Calculator");
            single_title.setText("Single Calculator");

        }
    });
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

this is the completely wrong approach to the problem ...

because the framework perfectly supports this out of the box, without messing around.

Android Studio even features a translation editor, where one can translate side-by-side.

see the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) and also [localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't support Welsh though.

Answer (score 0):

```
calc.setOnClickListener(this);
```

this keyword here reference to English's click listener that's why your basic functionality is not working.
Try to set all clicklistener outside english click listener's scope.
And your code will work fine.

Comment: Thanks will give this a go when I'm back at my computer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button calc = findViewById(R.id.buttoncalc);
Button reset = findViewById(R.id.buttonreset);
Button calc2 = findViewById(R.id.buttoncalc2);
Button reset2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonreset2);

setClicks();

english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        quantity1.setText("Quantity");
        total1.setText("Minimum");
        calc.setText("Calculation");
        reset.setText("Reset");
        calc2.setText("Calculation");
        reset2.setText("Reset");
        multi_title.setText("Multi Calculator");
        single_title.setText("Single Calculator");

    }
});

private void setClicks() {

calc.setOnClickListener(this);
reset.setOnClickListener(this);
calc2.setOnClickListener(this);
reset2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

Please try this and check it again

Comment: Thanks will give this a go when I'm back at my computer.